# Is it possible to drag images from MS Word and drop them into WEB-application?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-applications, drag-and-drop

I can drag files (images) from windows explorer into my WEB-application, preview them and upload to a server. What I would like to do is to grab a picture inserted in MS Word document, move it to my page, drop there and then upload to server. Is this possible?

This is a MVC app, right now I get image like this:

```
$('myDropControl')
       .on('drop', function (e) {

           e.preventDefault();
           var file = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0];
           var reader = new FileReader();
           reader.onload = function (evt) {
               $('myDropControl').html('').css('background-image', 'url(' + evt.target.result + ')');
               // then I do some other things to upload e.target.result to server
           }
           reader.readAsDataURL(file);
       });
```

Comment: Is a "WEB" application a specific CMS?  If not, then this is not possible without some heavy coding.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your question: what do you mean by "specific CMS"?  If event data that I receive in 'drop' event has reference to image data being dragged from MS Word, then there shall be a way to get it. Does this way exist?